# Giving a specific number to fields in my Db

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I want to give specific unique numbers to the following field in my db.
The column looks like:

```
August 2020
August 2020
August 2020
August 2020
September 2020
September 2020
September 2020
October 2020
November 2020
December 2020
December 2020
January 2021
January 2021
February 2021
March 2021.
```

I want the output in the following format:

```
August 2020         1
August 2020         1
August 2020         1
August 2020         1
September 2020      2
September 2020      2
September 2020      2
October 2020        3
November 2020       4
December 2020       5
December 2020       5
January 2021        6
January 2021        6
February 2021       7
March 2021          8
```

and so on. There can be n number of rows for each of the months name.
The result should have unique and incremental identifier on a month basis. And on change of year, it should continue and not restart from 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank()`

```
select col1, dense_rank() over(order by to_date(col1,'Month YYYY'))
from tablename
```

Comment: I tried this. It numbers October as 2 and September as 3

Comment: @AbHiNaVAgRaWaL, what is the data type of your column?

Comment: It is of text type

Comment: @AbHiNaVAgRaWaL, I've updated the answer - you can check now

Comment: @AbHiNaVAgRaWaL, If it helped u please mark it as accepted answer :)

Comment: will the counter number be 6 in case of jan 2021 in this case or 1? Keeping start as Aug 2020

Comment: 6 in this case but if u want it to be 1 then query need to modified a.but